# How to include graphicsmagick dynamic libraries in xcode

Tags: xcode, imagemagick, homebrew, graphicsmagick, magick++

I want to use GraphicsMagick Magick++ API in Xcode 9.2 and I have installed GraphicsMagick using `brew`. I know that header files and libraries can be  included in header search paths in Xcode by including the local installation directory:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.28/include
/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.28/lib
```

Is there any way to directly include these header files & dynamic libraries (.dylib) by copying it to my xcode project and giving relative path? Is local installation required for using Graphicsmagick C++ API?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to directly include these header files & dynamic libraries (.dylib) by copying it to my xcode project and giving relative path?

Here's a quick example using ImageMagick's [magick++](/questions/tagged/magick%2b%2b) library, but the process is the same for GraphicsMagick.

In Xcode's "Project Navigator" select the project (blue(print)? icon)

1. Navigate to "Build Settings".
2. Search for "Other"
3. Locate "Linking" -> "Other Linker Flags" and add configuration.

   ```
   -L/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.28/lib -lMagick++-6.Q16 -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16
   ```

   *Note:* You'll need to replace the `-l` values to what is installed in the directory. You can omit the `lib` prefix, and `.dylib` suffix (e.g. `libMagick++-6.Q16.dylib` would just be `-lMagick++-6.Q16`).
4. Locate "Apple LVM 7.0 - Custom Compiler Flags" -> "Other C Flags", and add configuration.

   ```
   -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.28/include
   ```
5. Preprocessor definitions may need to be added. Refer to the docs, but you may need to add the following in step 4.

   ```
   -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
   ```

   Actual flags & values are dependent on how you compiled & installed the libraries. There should be a `???-config` utility located in `/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.28/bin`, or a `???.pc` file located in `/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.28/lib/pkgconfig`. Just scan the `.pc` file for any `-D` options, and refer to HomeBrew docs if you can't find where pkgconfigs are stored.

> Is local installation required for using GraphicsMagick C++ API?

Yes. Including features from Magick++ will make this library a dependency for you project / solution. Also note that and delegates will also need to be included (libtiff, ghostscript, and freetype for example) if your planing to support additional formats/features.

Comment: @ emcconville, I want to know if it is possible to use graphicsmagick libraries without brew install? Can I manually copy built libraries(.dylib) and header files to xcode project location?

Comment: You can drag-n-drop them into the project navigator & they should populate in the linking stage, but you need to specify where the library headers are (step 4) as they are not included w/ dylib.

Comment: @ emcconville I am getting the following error:`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/graphicsmagick/lib/libGraphicsMagickWand.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/labuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gmTest-azfpamebcynxlzerhcpnpnvijhca/Build/Products/Debug/gmTest
  Reason: image not found`